# Fabric scripts for automated web app deployment no longer working on Jelastic version 4.9

Tags: ssh, fabric, paramiko, jelastic

I have developed several [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) scripts that automate the deployment of my web apps on Jelastic environments. These scripts have worked perfectly every time, until today. This issue is just baffling me as nothing on my scripts nor my environment has changed since the last successful execution; the only noteworthy change is that my Jelastic provider (ServNet Mexico) is now running version 4.9 of the Jelastic platform.

My local environment:

- Windows 10
- Python 2.7
- Fabric 1.13.1 (the most recent version, after I upgraded it today in order to see if it would make any difference)
- Paramiko 2.1.1 (as installed by PIP as a Fabric dependency)

I am having exactly the same problem on two other machines, both with MacOS Sierra and an equivalent Python and Fabric setup, but with older versions of the Fabric package (and its dependencies), which worked just fine a few days ago.

Outside of Fabric, SSH access via PuTTY (on Windows) and the terminal (MacOS) work normally. One thing that has changed recently is that at the start of the remote session an authentication banner is shown (which warns about the perils of SSH access, as shown below). I doubt this has anything to do with my problem.

As recommended [by this troubleshooting page on the Fabric documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/troubleshooting.html), I enabled the --show=debug flag for the fab command, as well as logging for Paramiko. The output on my command window looks like this (I omit some lines that could be considered private and sensitive, which, as far as I can tell, do not provide relevant information for the problem at hand):

```
Command line prompt>fab --show=debug my_task
Using fabfile '<path_to_fabric_script>'
Commands to run: my_task
Parallel tasks now using pool size of 0
<sensitive information omitted>
Parallel tasks now using pool size of 10
<sensitive information omitted>
[<jelastic_node>] run: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /var/lib/jelastic/backup && rm -f <file_to_delete>"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x3cd61d0L
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.1.1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-JSSHProxy
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client JSSHProxy)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:[u'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128'] server encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128'] client mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96'] client compress:[u'none'] server compress:[u'none'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha1-96
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for [gate.jl.serv.net.mx]:3022: <key>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key <key>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Auth banner:
  Welcome to Jelastic shell

  This shell will assist you in managing Jelastic applications.

    ============================== ATTENTION ==============================
   Shell access is rather powerful and you can accidentally damage your application.
   So please pay special attention to the actions you perform here.
    ============================== ATTENTION ==============================



INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
```

And the Fabric task just hangs at that point. No further output, no success or failure messages of any kind, no timeouts, no indication whatsoever of what might be happening. And the Fabric task's commands themselves do not run either, as the intended effect is not produced on the Jelastic node that is targeted by the Fabric task (the simplest task I have is just supposed to delete some backup files with the rm command; other tasks I have developed are more elaborate and they won't run either.)

I am inclined to think this issue is related either to the new (4.9) Jelastic version or its particular deployment on my Jelastic provider's infrastructure. Unfortunately, my provider was not helpful when I asked them for assistance on this matter.

I'd appreciate any clues as to what might be happening.

Comment: We need to investigate this case closer. Our developers are involved.

Comment: Please let me know if you find anything within the Jelastic platform that may be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try connect with option --keepalive=5..10

Comment: Can you provide more info on this? Has anyone tested this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be the issue with the paramico lib, you can check the issue [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/331#issuecomment-64129801).

Answer (score 0):

Such a behavior caused by the incorrect processing of the ssh welcome banner. But we have a workaround: edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and comment the following line:

```
Banner /etc/jmotd
```

then, restart the sshd daemon:

```
service sshd restart
```

If you will face any difficulties, feel free to contact us at support@jelastic.com.

*Best regards,
Jelastic Support Team*

Comment: I'm curious: When you say "such a behavior caused by the incorrect processing of the ssh welcome banner", who or what is doing the incorrect processing, exactly? Is it Fabric/Paramiko or something in the Jelastic platform itself? I haven't tried the proposed solution yet. I'll let you know when I do.

Comment: This is an issue with the Paramiko, you can google it https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=paramiko+ssh+banner

Comment: I am unable to apply the workaround. There is, in fact, a `sshd_config` file (on both the Tomcat and PostgreSQL nodes of my Jelastic environments), but access is denied when attempting to open it either on the SSH session or via the dashboard. There's also a `ssh_config` file in the same directory, and it can be opened but it doesn't have the "Banner" line mentioned on the description of the workaround.